# How do I organize information between the two Xbox 360's in the same house?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

Through a twist of fate, I have 2 xbox 360's to use in different rooms in my house.  Let's call them "original" and "new".

The question is: How do I organize information between the 2 consoles?

There are 2 main users... each will mainly be using their own console.

- Both users have saved games from borderlands splitscreen coop on the original.  I'd like to preserve the ability to do splitscreen coop.
- Both users have saved games from Mass Effect 1 and 2 on the original.
- There are some xbox live games downloaded (such as Carcassonne) on the original that we'd like on both.

Nothing is currently networked and there are is one existing xbox live silver account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get two memory units (or USB drives if you have the newer XBox360 Slim). Store each profile on one along with any save file you'd like to have available for on both consoles.

That's what me and my bf do

Also, downloaded content works A) on the console it was downloaded on and B) from the profile who downloaded it. So have your gold membership profile download content on his/her non-primary console first to add the license to that HDD, then to their primary console 2nd and you'll be able to use the content from both consoles.

Comment: They might have to get USB drives instead: the 360 slim doesn't have slots for MUs. It's the same principle, though, saving the profiles on the flash drives ... that also makes it much easier to play at other people's houses. Also, there are a handful of older XBLA games for which the DRM is messed up, and even if the profile that purchased the game is logged in, the game may only be available in trial mode ... but those are rare, and it's best not to worry about it until it happens.

Comment: some flash drives cannot work on the xbox 360, either it gets a performance warning or a "cant configure" message. however sandisk sells a branded configured xbox 360 flash drive. you can get more information from here: http://www.xbox.com/en-US/storage

Comment: I picked up 2 4Gig flash drives for less than $10 each.  Put a profile on each and we're saving games to them.  Works great.

Comment: In addition to saved games, you can usually store DLC (like additional maps from CoD) on the USB drive also. I believe the limit to the USB thumb drive size is 8gb.