# How can I move my Mass Effect 2 save between Xboxes?

Tags: xbox-360, mass-effect-2

I know that when you beat the final boss of Mass Effect, the game made an "endgame" save that the player does not have access to.  To remedy this when Mass Effect 2 came out (and I had a new Xbox) I simply transferred over my last Mass Effect save before the last boss fight and beat it again to create an endgame save on my new system.

In Mass Effect 2, however, we can't transfer game saves (and I have yet another new Xbox).  I'm wondering if I can start up my most recent Mass Effect 2 save file on my old system, make a save to my flash drive, load the game from the flash drive on my new Xbox, and then make a save to the HDD on my new Xbox and load it in Mass Effect 3.  The only problem with this is if Mass Effect 2 generates an endgame save similar to how Mass Effect did or if I can't specify which storage device to save to.  Is there a way to change your storage device to save to when you've chosen a different storage device to load from?

I've continued playing ME:2 after the endgame (for the DLC missions) and don't have a save before the final mission anymore.  If ME:3 imports based on an endgame save of ME:2 then I think I'm screwed.  Does anyone know if ME:2 creates an endgame save?  If so, has anyone heard anything from BioWare about whether or not the ME:3 import system will be based on that save or if it is based on any save after you have beaten the final mission?

**Edit: Resolved:** The Xbox would not let me 'Copy' my game save to a new location, but I was able to 'Move' it to cloud storage.  Thank you Ktash for the suggestions (could have sworn I tried that).

Comment: Until the 6th, anything we say will likely be speculation, but that said, why in the world do you think that you "can't transfer game saves"?

Comment: My Xbox 360 gives me an error message: "Can't Transfer Item: This item cannot be transferred between storage devices."

Comment: Are you copying or moving? Check out [this forum post](http://forums.gametrailers.com/thread/mass-effect-2-and-fable-2-save/1094314) for what looks to be tips on solving that problem.

Comment: So what you're really asking is how to transfer a ME2 savegame from one XBox 360 to another?  This has nothing to do with ME3, making the title extremely misleading.

Comment: As a side note, now might be a good time to switch to cloud storage for your game saves.

Comment: The last sentence of your question is speculative until the 6th, but I'm keeping this open because the heart of your question involves how to transfer the saves between xboxes.

Comment: @ BlueRaja - I was asking about transferring ME2 gamesaves and also asking about if BioWare had made a statement about how importing would work from ME2 to ME3 (similar to how they did for Mass Effect to ME2 transfers before ME2 was released).  Perhaps I should have separated the questions into two separate questions though in order to make things more clear and concise.

Comment: @Ktash I thought I had tried both, but perhaps I only tried copying?  The system with the ME2 saves is not with me right now, but I will double-check that the next chance I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't shed any light on how to troubleshoot your file transfer issues, I *can* shed some light on how Mass Effect 2 saves work (and this should be true across all platforms).

Every Mass Effect 2 save file has a "QuestCompletion" variable that can be one of three values. Gibbed's save editor has dubbed these, "Quest Incomplete", "Lived To Fight Again", and "Went Out in a Blaze of Glory".

There is no "mission complete" save generated by ME2 like there is in ME1. Instead, *every* save file has this variable in one of the three states. Presumably, only saves where Shepherd "Lived to Fight Again" will be viable to import, as Bioware has previously stated dead Commander Shepherds won't be importable into ME3. (And obviously, you can't import without beating the game).

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering if I can start up my most recent Mass Effect 2 save file on my old system, make a save to my flash drive, load the game from the flash drive on my new Xbox,

You can do this:

1. Use the Memory tool on the old xbox to copy your ME2 save to your flash drive.
2. Use the Memory tool on the new xbox to copy your ME2 save from the flash drive.

This should work with both playable and endgame ME2 saves.

Note: you may need to move your gamertag as well.

PS: you may also be interested in [this question/answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21386/how-do-i-organize-information-between-the-two-xbox-360s-in-the-same-house).

Comment: I've tried copying my ME2 saves to my flash drive but I get an error message: "Can't Transfer Item: This item cannot be transferred between storage devices."

Answer (score 0):

Since the file has the no move flag set, what you can do is as you suggested, open the game then immediately save in-game to another device. In this case you can either save to a flash device or save to the cloud storage if you have gold.

Answer (score 0):

I "Move" the saved file to (formatted for the Xbox) UBS flash drive. Took the USB to PC, open with window explorer, on the tabs>view> check Hidden Items/files. copy to an empty folder.

Now back to Xbox with the UBS and "Move" file back where you got it from.
Then, take UBS back to PC to copy back the file on the Flash drive and that is it!

Note: I will recommend to use a completely empty USB drive and one item at the time since the files are weirdly named/numbered