# At what point is the "Final Save" created for import to Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-2

I'm assuming that the endgame save or final save or whatever you want to call it for Mass Effect 2 is created after your decision regarding the Collector Base.

What I wish to know, is: will it re-save with new information based on any DLC I complete?

For example, if I finish the main mission, and then proceed to finish the Arrival DLC, will my final save be updated so that in ME3 it knows I finished the Arrival DLC?

The reason I ask is because I know there could be some effect in ME3 based on what you did in DLC, so if my final save (I'm almost there) doesn't update, then that means that I'll want to complete all of the DLC before taking the fight to the collectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every Mass Effect 2 save file has a "QuestCompletion" variable that can be one of three values. Gibbed's save editor has dubbed these, "Quest Incomplete", "Lived To Fight Again", and "Went Out in a Blaze of Glory".

There is no "mission complete" save generated by ME2 like there is in ME1. Instead, every save file has this variable in one of the three states. Presumably, only saves where Shepard "Lived to Fight Again" will be viable to import, as Bioware has previously stated dead Commander Shephards won't be importable into ME3. (And obviously, you can't import without beating the game).

(Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/52493/336)

When importing into Mass Effect 3, you get to pick the actual save to import (i.e., quick, auto, or manual). Your save is always current, so there should be no worry about keeping your save "updated", other than simply saving normally from playing the game.

Comment: Thank god. It would have felt a bit odd to finish Arrival and then defeat the Collectors. Now at least I can play it in chronological order and not miss out on anything.

Comment: Wait, so when I do the import, it'll list all save points from a particular career that have QuestCompletion set to Lived to Fight Again?

Comment: @MrSmooth: playing Arrival before the suicide mission actually works pretty well.  Hackett's "debrief" has slightly different lines if done before or after the suicide mission.

Comment: Also, another point for the reason I'm glad I can finish the Collector Mission first is that now I can do all of the DLC with Legion in my squad (he's by far the best character) instead of only getting him for the Collector Mission.

Comment: @MBraedley yes. You pick a profile first, and then a list of eligible saves.